# How do I get the tab id of a tab that is running content.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that closes a certain website as soon as it loads, and have a content.js page and a background.js page. The background.js page works and is waiting for a message from content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, _, sendResponse) {
  if (msg.closeTab) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(msg.tabID);
  }
});
```

And the code to send the message in content.js is:

```
addButton("Close this tab.", function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({closeTab: true, tabID: tab.id});
});
```

but the problem I am having is that `tab` is undefined.
I'm using a button just to test the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your message listener function, you can use the second argument to retrieve the caller's tab id, you cannot get the tab id from the content script.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse){
    if (msg.closeTab){
        chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id)
    }
});
```

And the content.js would be

```
addButton("Close this tab", function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({closeTab:true});
});
```

See [chrome.runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage), especially the second argument `sender`.

Comment: What exactly does `_` represent?